# Are there any requirements for the internet for signalmaster to work?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, webrtc, simplewebrtc

I set up a WebRTC solution using signalmaster, simpleWebRTC and restund on my own server. I tried with 5 or 6 different people, and it all worked, except for one person who could not connect. I then asked that person to switch his internet to use his mobile phone's hotspot, and then it worked for him as well, which made me conclude that something in his router or whatnot was blocking the connection.

I don't have a lot of details, and I don't expect a specific answer, but is there anything that would stop the connection from being made between two clients in simpleWebRTC?

Comment: UDP ports might be blocked, does your restund server support TCP transport?

Comment: @mido I think so... it shows both ucp and tcp ports have been opened. How can I check if UDP ports are blocked on the client computer? I have physical access to the client computer.

Comment: it is not just client's computer, it might be his network( corporate proxy in my case) is blocking udp ports, not sure how to test udp ports are open in network.....

Comment: @mido Yeah the problem seems to be on his network, not the computer. He tried with three or four computers, all didn't work, until he switched to his mobile network.